# IgniteMesssaging works in sync mode

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, messaging, ignite

It seems that Ignite(2.0) Messaging's send function works in sync mode, it will be blocked be the listener. And below is my testing code.

```
ignite.message().localListen("TEST", (nodeId, Msg) -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    return true;
});



for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    ignite.message().send("TEST", "Hello World");
}
```

It cost about 50 seconds to send 100 messages, and it is almost equals the sleep time 500 ms * 100.  seems the send function in sync mode not in async mode.

Does anybody know how to change the send function in async mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems async listener invocation was missed while adding new API, but you still have two options:

1. Use deprecated `withAsync()`, unless `sendAsync()` will be added.
2. Pass your own Executor in predicate, if you always return true, for example.

I've just opened a ticket for that [IGNITE-5570](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5570)

Comment: Hi Mitya, thanks for your answer, yes, we can use `withAsync()` to send the message in async mode, but do you know why this function has been deprecated in v2?
And another question, is the function `sendOrdered()` always in sync mode, no matter we use `withAsync()` or not?

Comment: `withAsync()` is confusing API, because not all methods respect that flag, so decided to change it by adding `xxxAsync()` methods that return future. So in AI 3.0 old API will be removed completely. And yes, `sendOrdered()` doesn't check async flag, probably this feature was missed or was not required before.

Comment: So, are you planning to release 2 apis for sending message in async mode, one is `sendAsync()` and the other is `sendOrderedAsync()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're testing within one node. In this case there is no message sent and listener is invoked synchronously. Network communication is asynchronous in Ignite, so if you do the testing on two nodes, you should not see such behavior.